# how can i get contacts from contact list and how can i implements functionality from onCreate() onwards

Tags: android

hi all i am implementing android code for getting the contacts from contact list (i mean get the phone number, name ,address, and email ID ) if i enter number mobile will show the above details. now i unable to get those detail so kindly help me from onCreate() method onwords

and how can implements xml files and oncreate() method

Comment: "i am implementing" ... Sorry, it sounds very much like you're not implementing anything. At least try to learn the platform and take a stab at doing it yourself. If you have specific problems that come up, come back and find help on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go through some basic tutorials. Then read this [Android Contacts Api](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html).